# Sampling from imported data frame in R

Tags: r, statistics

Why is length(myData) = 11 ? there are 4548 observations of 11 variables, so shouldn't length(myData) = 4548? I can't take a sample of size 100 because of this.

[image]

Comment: Please use a small reproducible example and expected output instead of just images.  `length` by default for a data.frame gives the number of columns.  You can check `dim(myData)` or `str(myData)` to understand more about the data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please only use screenshots to display something inherently visual and nontabular like a plot. For code, warnings, errors, etc., please take type to reproduce the text in your question, with proper formatting.

Comment: `iris[sample.int(nrow(iris), 10), ]`

Answer (score 1):

You have 11 columns in your `data.frame`. Recall that a `data.frame` is basically a `list` of vectors which all have the same length. So running `length` on a `data.frame` does not return the number of rows but the length of the vector (i.e. the number of columns).  Use `nrow` instead. Compare the following:

```
x <- data.frame(N = rnorm(10), U = runif(10)) # A 10 by 2 data.frame
print(x)
#            N          U
#1  -0.3268912 0.54028083
#2  -1.2258164 0.92542376
#3   0.3019713 0.94697492
#4   0.2705930 0.63219863
#5  -0.3168112 0.58040885
#6   2.2770266 0.03954027
#7   1.8342293 0.72598938
#8   1.1173648 0.44547958
#9  -0.7042288 0.09008339
#10 -0.6354642 0.85035006

length(x)
# [1] 2

nrow(x) 
# [1] 10

ncol(x)
# [1] 2

dim(x)
#[1] 10  2
```

**Edit:** As @jogo writes in the comments, you can sample `m` random rows with something like:

```
m <- 5
x[sample(nrow(x), m), ]
```

Note this uses the `x[<subset of rows>, <subset of cols>]` notation. See `help("[")`.

Comment: Thanks ! how would you then sample 100 random samples out of the 4548 observations in my dataframe ? i.e get a random sample 100 rows in the data frame

Comment: @JackHuang `myData[sample.int(nrow(myData), 100), ]`

Comment: @JackHuang I've edited my answer, basically writing what jogo also suggests.